# Printing all elements of an array.

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple piece of code, but there is one part that I cannot complete. 
How do I print all the elements of an array after I have inputted them from the keyboard in a for loop,

here is the code. 
Thanks.

```
  final int MAX = 5;
  String [] names = new String[MAX];

  for(int index = 0; index < MAX; index++){
     System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
     names[index]=keyboard.nextLine();
  }
  System.out.println(names);
```

Comment: make another for loop and print out each one separately there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for`loop, to loop over the array.

```
for(int index = 0; index < names.length; index++){
  System.out.println(names[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly print as (faster as single loop):

```
 String [] names = new String[MAX];
 for(int index = 0; index < MAX; index++)
{
 System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
 names[index]=keyboard.nextLine();
 System.out.println(names[index]);
}
```

or  you can do like this :

```
String [] names = new String[MAX];
for(int index = 0; index < MAX; index++)
{
 System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
 names[index]=keyboard.nextLine();
 }
 for(int index = 0; index < MAX; index++)
{
 System.out.println(names[index]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString(names)`call `toString()` api of `Arrays` class to print array.

```
public static String toString(Object[] a)
```

Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified `array`.

```
  for(int index = 0; index < MAX; index++){
     System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
     names[index]=keyboard.nextLine();
  }

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ABC {
public static void main(String []args) {
    final int MAX = 5;
      String [] names = new String[MAX];
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int index = 0; index < names.length; index++){
         System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
         names[index] = input.nextLine(); //Getting names from keyboard
      }
        System.out.println("The names are as follows : "); 
      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i]);     //Printing the names
    }
   }
}
```